# How to fix "ValueError: Length mismatch"

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm getting an error:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 5 elements, new values have 6 
elements
```

When I run my base code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

READ = "C:\\Users\\Ashley\\Biotech Data Center 4.1.21.xlsx"

stocks = "BHVN"

PipelineData = pd.read_excel(READ, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None, index_col=0)
pipelinecolstitle = pd.read_excel(READ, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=None,nrows=1).values[0]
PipelineData.columns = pipelinecolstitle
colspipe= ['Catalyst']
tt = PipelineData[colspipe]

for i in stocks:
    t = tt.loc[(PipelineData['Ticker']==i)]
    print(t)
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    cols = ["Catalyst"]

    axMain = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
    table = plt.subplot(2,1,2, frameon=False)

    axMain.plot([1,2,7])
    table = ax.table(cellText=t, loc='upper center',colLabels=cols)
    table.axis("off")

plt.show()
```

It seems like it doesn't like index_col=0
If I change the index_col=None it gives me a KeyError: 0

Comment: Please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) / sample data that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 0):

This error is probably raised by this assignement `PipelineData.columns = pipelinecolstitle`, meaning that the number of columns of *PipelineData* is not equal to *pipelinecolstitle* length.

Check that `PipelineData.shape[1] == len(pipelinecolstitle)`

Comment: Both of them are equal at 6.